# Double poles in S-matrx

Tags: particle-physics, s-matrix-theory

Are double (or higher) poles forbidden in general in an S-matrix? If so, why? If not, under which conditions can they appear, and what would be the interpretation?

Comment: I'd guess that if the spectrum is degenerate, S-matrix will have non-simple poles.

Comment: AFAIK, degeneracy is related to the residue of the pole, not with its order. That being said, I do believe that poles of higher order may arise if there are several particles with the same mass and spin in the spectrum of the theory.

Comment: It makes sense to me that degeneracy should not generate higher-order poles (intuitively if two simple pole merge, you get one simple pole with the sum of the residues), but isn't multiple particle of the same mass & spin itself a type of degeneracy?

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking of pole merge as that of $\frac1{z^2+a}$ as $a\to0$, not that of $\frac n{z-a}+\frac1{z+a}$ in the same limit. I understand now that the former type of merge is not what one gets in S-matrix...